# Find out average by Group Wise and after that convert column to row

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table 'tbTest' like this:

```
id | q1 | q2 | q3 | type
---+----+----+----+---------
 1 |  1 |  2 |  3 | student
 2 |  2 |  1 |  3 | student
 3 |  1 |  3 |  2 | student
 4 |  3 |  1 |NULL| alumni
 5 |  2 |  1 |NULL| alumni
 6 |  2 |  2 |  1 | student
```

Now I want average GroupWise and convert like it:

```
q  | Student | Alumni
---+---------+--------    
q1 |   1.5   |  2.5
q2 |   2     |  1
q3 |   2.5   |  NULL
```

Comment: Make union of queries for q1, q2 and q3.

Comment: In each of the `q` queries you then make `AVG` for `student` and `AVG` for `alumni`.
Within each `AVG` you can use `CASE` of `type` column value to apply only values for the given type.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was closed.  The question seems quite clear to me (and apparently to two other people who provided answers), about something relevant to Stack Overflow.  The only shortcoming is the lack of specific database tag.

Comment: Hi Gordon@[1144035], I used Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the C# tag, I am going to assume you are using SQL Server.  My recommendation is to unpivot the data using apply and then reaggregate:

```
select v.q,
       avg(case when t.type = 'student' then v.val * 1.0 end) as student,
       avg(case when t.type = 'alumni' then v.val * 1.0 end) as alumni
from tbTest t cross apply
     (values ('q1', t.q1), ('q2', t.q2), ('q3', t.q3)) v(q, val)
group by v.q;
```

Similar logic can be implemented in other databases either using `union all` or an explicit `union all`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0f590d81e6f2a15352fc7a23fdf8e5a3) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I got some error like this:  "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "q.val" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "q.val" could not be bound."

Comment: @NeloySarothi . . . That was a typo.

Comment: sorry sir, it was my fault, I didn't notice that there are some mistake like column name. After modification now your SQL run swiftly. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The operation you want is commonly called `PIVOT` in different RDBMS, but it's not standard SQL and not supported by every RDBMS.

If you don't have many groups, then you can instead hardcode your query for each group (just like @Dusan suggested)

```
SELECT 
  'q1' as q
  (SELECT AVG(q1) WHERE type='student') as student,
  (SELECT AVG(q1) WHERE type='alumni') as alumni
FROM tbTest
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  'q2'
  (SELECT AVG(q2) WHERE type='student'),
  (SELECT AVG(q2) WHERE type='alumni')
FROM tbTest
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  'q3'
  (SELECT AVG(q3) WHERE type='student'),
  (SELECT AVG(q3) WHERE type='alumni')
FROM tbTest
```